# Swift - ContainerView covering ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers

I have a `ViewController` and a `containerView`. The problem is that my `containerView` is covering my `ViewController` so I can't click the `buttons` inside my `ViewController`.

[image]

I know I can `self.view.sendSubviewToBack(containerView)` but that doesn't solve my problem because I actually want the containerView(bottomBar + settingsButton) to be visible on the foreground.

Is there any way I can have the `containerView` on top of my `ViewController` and still be able to click the buttons inside my `ViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse the containment ,  the vc that have the addButton and the bottom bar should hold the other vc and by this you can control the visibility of the childVC ( the one the pop out when you click add ) by sending it back to what you need it visible above it

Comment: sorry I am not really following you. Why would it make a difference? I want the bottomBar and the settingsButton to be always there.

Comment: for the containerView to be in top it should have a height constraint that make the ones below it clickable if you can do this then it's another option

Comment: Do you mean I should just add a height constraint??

Comment: why would that make the ones below it clickable?

Comment: as you will leave space either in top or bottom (not a full screen height ) where items that need to clickable are visible if this doesn't go with your design then my answer is the only way

Comment: it's logical that the hosting vc should be the container not the child where according to your design it's the 1 that have the plus and bottomBar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202470/discussion-between-chris-and-sh-khan).